# Jakarta Persistence issue in Kotlin - error accessing field by reflection for persistent property

Tags: kotlin, jpa

I have a unit test in Kotlin which works as expected and data appears in the database, but when I try to call Ktor Application through HTTP, I get an exception error stating "jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException to JPA PersistenceException : Error accessing field [private java.lang.String eu.mariyo.ai1.kernel.infrastructure.jakarta.Registration.id] by reflection for persistent property [eu.mariyo.ai1.kernel.infrastructure.jakarta.Registration#id]".

Can someone help with this issue? Here's the unit test:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `create new registration for unknown user`() {
        // Given
        val request = RegistrationRequest(
            DataProvider.emailRandom(),
            DataProvider.name,
            DataProvider.companyName,
            DataProvider.vatRandom()
        )

        // When
        Context.buildSessionFactory().inTransaction { session ->
            session.persist(
                Registration(
                    UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                    request.userEmail,
                    request.userName,
                    request.companyName,
                    request.vat,
                    false,
                )
            )
        }

        // Then
        repository.hasUnconfirmedRegistration(request)
    }
```

But when I try to call Ktor Application through HTTP, I fails on this exception:

```
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: 
Converting `org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException` 
to JPA `PersistenceException` : 
Error accessing field [private java.lang.String eu.mariyo.ai1.kernel.infrastructure.jakarta.Registration.id] 
by reflection for persistent property 
[eu.mariyo.ai1.kernel.infrastructure.jakarta.Registration#id] : 
Registration(id=cbb7c96e-62e0-48db-9a2e-a2557512726f, userEmail=john.unknown.0@example.com, userName=John Unknown, companyName=Unknown Company Ltd. (ID: 0), vat=VAT0, confirmed=false)
```

This is whole Ktor part:

```kotlin
fun Route.myRoutes() {
    post("/registration") {
        val requestParams = call.receiveParameters()

        Context.buildSessionFactory().inTransaction { session ->
            session.persist(
                Registration(
                    UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                    requestParams["userEmail"].toString(),
                    requestParams["userName"].toString(),
                    requestParams["companyName"].toString(),
                    requestParams["companyVat"].toString(),
                    false,
                )
            )
        }

        call.respondHtml(HttpStatusCode.OK, HTML::registration)
    }
}
```

The last block to puzzle is the Context object:

```kotlin
object Context {

    private val hibernateConfiguration = buildConfiguration()
    val sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory()

    private fun entities() = listOf(User::class, Registration::class)

    public fun buildSessionFactory(): SessionFactory {
        val sessionFactory = hibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(hibernateConfiguration.properties)
                .build()
        )

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(object : Thread() {
            override fun run() {
                sessionFactory.close()
            }
        })

        return sessionFactory
    }

    private fun buildConfiguration(): Configuration {
        val configuration = Configuration()
        configuration.properties = getHibernateProperties()
        entities().forEach { configuration.addAnnotatedClass(it.java) }
        return configuration
    }

    private fun getHibernateProperties(): Properties {
        val hibernateProperties = Properties()
        val file = File("./ops/docker/.env")

        FileInputStream(file).use { hibernateProperties.load(it) }

        val database = hibernateProperties["MYSQL_FIXTURE_DATABASE"]
        val port = hibernateProperties["HOST_MYSQL_FIXTURE_PORT"]

        hibernateProperties[Environment.DRIVER] = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
        hibernateProperties[Environment.URL] = "jdbc:mariadb://0.0.0.0:$port/$database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
        hibernateProperties[Environment.USER] = hibernateProperties["MYSQL_FIXTURE_USER"]
        hibernateProperties[Environment.PASS] = hibernateProperties["MYSQL_FIXTURE_PASSWORD"]
        hibernateProperties[Environment.DIALECT] = "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB10Dialect"
        hibernateProperties[Environment.SHOW_SQL] = true
        hibernateProperties[Environment.FORMAT_SQL] = true
        hibernateProperties[Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS] = "managed"
        hibernateProperties[Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO] = "update"

        //C3PO
        hibernateProperties["hibernate.c3p0.min_size"] = 1000
        hibernateProperties["hibernate.c3p0.max_size"] = 2000
        hibernateProperties["hibernate.c3p0.timeout"] = 120
        hibernateProperties["hibernate.c3p0.max_statements"] = 2000

        return hibernateProperties
    }
}
```